# Split a TableRow in 3 columns

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout, tablerow

I want 1 `TextView` and 2 `Buttons` in a `TableRow`.
Here is an example (application screenshot) of how I want it to look like. I drew it in  paint:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="8"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

    </TableRow>
```

// note the use of weightSum, and weight if thats what you want

Comment: i would suggest to use weights, and not the actual size, because the fixed size would work fine in you screen size. weights are proportional.

Comment: Note: The weightSum is **optional**, because Android calculates the sum by of the children weights automatically.

Answer (score 3):

```
   <TableRow 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:weightSum="100"
       >
       <EditText 
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="50"
           />
       <Button 
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_weight="25"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Button1"
           />
       <Button 
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_weight="25"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Button2"
           />
   </TableRow>
```

you can change the weight of the EditText or the Buttons as your requirements

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for - particularly useful when there is a lot happening in the table.